# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment?

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error?

```
    playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Here's the code. I think it looks fine, but I may have some pretty bad mistakes. sorry for the dumb question:

```
print ("********* WELCOME TO A BLACKJACK GAME *********")

endProgram = False


from random import randint

computerHand1 = randint(1,11)
computerHand2 = randint(1,11)

print ("Dealer's cards: " + "X and " + str(computerHand2))

totalcomputerHand = computerHand1 + computerHand2

playerHand = randint(1,11)

playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)

print ("Your cards are: " + str(playerHand[1]) + " , " + str(playerHand[2]))

while endProgram == False:   
    totalplayerHand = playerHand[1] + playerHand[2] + playerHand[3] + playerHand[4] + playerHand[5] + playerHand[6] + playerHand[7] + playerHand[8] + playerHand[9] + playerHand[10] + playerHand[11] + playerHand[12] + playerHand[13] + playerHand[14] + playerHand[15] + playerHand[16] + playerHand[17] + playerHand[18] + playerHand[19] + playerHand[20] + playerHand[21]

    if totalplayerHand == (21):
        if totalcomputerHand == (21):
            endProgram = True
            print ("Dealer's hand equals 21 and your hand equals 21. This is a draw")
        if totalcomputerHand < (21):
            endProgram = True
            print ("Dealer's hand equals " + str(totalcomputerHand) + " and your hand equals 21. You have won the game")

    counter = 3
```

I am trying to do arrays which are lists in python (for the first time), and I am also new to coding and python.

Comment: I changed it to this ' playerHand = []

playerHand[0] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11) ' But now I get this error: playerHand[0] = randint(1,11)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
playerHand = randint(1,11)
```

You assign playerHand the return from `randint`, which is an `int`. Then here:

```
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
```

You attempt to index into `playerHand` like it is an array. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `playerHand` to a number.

```
playerHand = randint(1,11)
```

If you type the above line into a terminal, you will find that it is a number and not a list.

```
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

The kind of assignment you are doing is here, with the `[1]` and `[2]` is for list or dictionary elements (and other ones that support *item assignment* as your error message explains).

You probably meant to do something like

```
computerHand1 = randint(1,11)
computerHand2 = randint(1,11)
```

in which case the proper code would be

```
playerHand1 = randint(1,11)
playerHand2 = randint(1,11)
```

Now... is this really the right way to structure the problem as a whole? I think we can do better in terms of data structures, but this small adjustment will get rid of your error.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I had it before I asked the question. But I am trying to do arrays, because if I do it the other way, I will have to write a lot of unnecessary lines of code, otherwise the game won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an int (not a list):

```
playerHand = randint(1,11)
```

To make a list you want to start like this:

```
playerHand = []
```

Then, you can assign the values to the indices, as you are trying to do:

```
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

Although, python starts the list indices with `0`, not `1`.

Note that also the easiest way to add new items to a list the first time is with `extend` or `append`:

```
playerHand.append(randint(1,11))
```

Indexing only works when you already have items in the list -- where you can give an index less than `len(playerHand)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are have:

```
playerHand = randint(1,11)
```

`playerHand` is now a variable correct? When you attempt:

```
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

You are treating the variable `playerHand` as a list now, creating the error. To prevent this error, you probably need to make `playerHand` a list instead like this:

```
playerHand = []
```

to prevent the error.
You can also do this:

```
playerHand1 = randint(1, 11)
playerHand2 = randint(1, 11)
```

You can use @Wally Beaver's answer but you need to fix one thing. From this:

```
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

to this:

```
playerHand[0] = randint(1,11)
playerHand[1] = randint(1,11)
```

Why? Because all lists start with 0, not 1. If you don't do this, another error will appear. To add stuff to your list, do this instead:

```
playerHand1 = randint(1, 11)
playerHand2 = randint(1, 11)
playerHand.append (playerHand1)
playerHand.append (playerHand2)
```

This will get rid of your list assignment error. You can see how by adding this right after:

```
print playerHand1, playerHand2
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: but then I get this error 'playerHand[0] = randint(1,11)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range'

Answer (score 1):

You need make a list.

The wrong version:

```
    playerHand = randint(1,11) ## return list
    playerHand[1] = randint(1,11) ## playerHand is not a list
    playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

The correct version:

```
playerHand = []

playerHand[1] = randint(1,11) ## playerHand is a list !!
playerHand[2] = randint(1,11)
```

Comment: This is not correct, you need the list or appropriate size to assign the items. Indexes should be `[0]` and `[1]` instead and declaration something like `playerHand = [None, None]`

Answer (score 0):

This code have some wrong moments, for example, in lines:

```
while endProgram == False:   
totalplayerHand = playerHand[1] + playerHand[2] + playerHand[3] + playerHand[4] + playerHand[5] + playerHand[6] + playerHand[7] + playerHand[8]
```

So, you don't have any values into *playerHand* array, except first two.

And make *playerHand* as array, 'cause now you have an integer number.